# Remove hardcoded "read more" button when using <!--more-->

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, and I'm guessing some advanced filters and stuff are involved, but here goes. How can I make the "read more" button that I coded into the content loop in my Wordpress blog display:none when I'm using the < !--more--> tag manually?

When I'm using it now, both "read more" buttons are visible.

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'dsgn' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>
        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></span>
        </div>

        <img class="post-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pencil.png"> 

        <div class="seperator">
            <div class="sepen"></div>
            <div class="septo"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="entry-excerpt">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

        <?php the_content( __( 'read more <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'dsgn' ) ); ?>

        <?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link\">".__( '<span>read more</span>', 'dsgn' ). '</a>' ?>
        <div class="entry-footer-fix"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I was just thinking what I needed was to filter out the echoed button if I use the <!--more--> tag. I'm not sure about the javascript click handler, how do I find that? :) *EDIT* The buttons aren't really a problem, they do what they're supposed to do, but the echoed button doesn't disappear because it's not inside the content..

Comment: Does your "read more" section open in the same page? Any interaction on a page that does not open a new page is done by javascript.

Comment: The "read more" section takes me to the the single.php view of the post, so that's working fine. The problem is that I have a duplicate of the button.

Comment: So you only want to use your hard coded one if you haven't explicitly set a `<!--more-->` break in the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting two "read more" tags. Stop doing this:

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link\">".__( '<span>read more</span>', 'dsgn' ). '</a>' ?>
```

[`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) will already output a "read more" tag. It takes your desired "read more" snippet as an argument and automatically decides whether to show either the entire post or just the first part along with your given "read more" snippet. As mentioned in the documentation, you can override the automatic behavior (force entire/partial content) by changing the global variable `$more`.

In other words, you should never need to `echo` your own "read more" tag unless you always want to it to be visible.